# Why are the points that I have to check if the limit exists for this function (Thomae function?) finite?

Tags: calculus

I am reading Chapter 5 of *Spivaks*. One of his examples is the function $f$ defined as 0 if $x$ is irrational and between 0 and 1,  or $\frac{1}{q}$ if $\frac{p}{q}$ is irreducible and between $0 < x < 1$. Here is a copy of his proof from a previous question which I looked at before asking this question: Pedro Tamaroff (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23350/pedro-tamaroff), What exactly is going on when we're finding a limit?, URL (version: 2013-01-10): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/195969. One of the things that I found confusing about the proof *Spivak* gave was how he was able to conclude that the points at which the limit could be false are finite. Spivak states, "Let $n$ be a natural number so large that $\frac{1}{n} \leq e$. Notice that the only numbers $x$ for which the limit could be false are $1/2;1/3;2/3;1/4;3/4;...;1/n,...\frac{n-1}{n}$"

Let's say the epsilon I choose is $1/10$, and my $n = 11$ (both of which satisfy his statement), then the numbers I would have to check would be: $1/2;...;1/11...10/11$. In my mind, however, there are more numbers then the ones stated by Spivak that can be used to show that the limit is false such as $1/12,...11/12;1/13...12/13$, and I don't understand why this is not the case. I recognize the other parts of the proof, except for this.Furthermore, in an example prior to this one, Spivak shows the function $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is rational and 0 if $x$ is irrational, and states that the limit can not be found which I think I understand, but this "new" function has the limit of 0 at all a from $(0,1)$. I think this has to do with the $\frac{1}{q}$ aspect of this "new" function, but I don't really understand how or why. Any help from just helping me gain an intuition for the two functions, to links to other questions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your counterexamples are wrong, i.e $\frac{1}{12}$ does not make the statement false as $\frac{1}{12} < \frac{1}{10}$.

Comment: Yes, I understand that per Spivaks statement, my counterexample is wrong, but I don't understand why his statement is correct.